# How to upgrade from python 2.7 to the latest version of python

Tags: apt, upgrade, python, python-2.7

I have python 2.7.15+ installed and I want to upgrade to the latest version 3.7. I have come across the command from net

> sudo apt-get install python 3.3.3

But this command adds another software right, it's not replacing python 2.7  How should I proceed? Would be grateful for any help.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Release:    18.04

Codename:   bionic

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 comes with `python3` (3.6.5-3) installed.  `python2` is a different system to `python3`, and `python2` doesn't upgrade past 2.7.17-1  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=python  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3&searchon=names).   Check you've applied all upgrades, as your system should report 18.04.4 (not 18.04.3)

Comment: You cannot remove Python2 from Ubuntu so far. You can only add Python3 on your Ubuntu installation. It is expected that Ubuntu 20.04 will be "Python2-free", but I doubt it. :(

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Ubuntu 20.04 & flavors ISOs have been completely free of `python2` (it was renamed) for some time now.  New installs of all flavors have no `python2`, which has led to some bug reports with 3rd party packages that rely on `python` (*being python[2]; no longer installing cleanly))

Comment: @FedonKadifeli   I also noticed it awhile back when my system (4+ months now 20.04) had `python2` removed with normal upgrades and a script I run weekly wouldn't anymore...  (script was converted to `python3` and all good again..)  It's been tested not just with 'new' installs.

Comment: After the commands $ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade, I got it as 18.04.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you replace python 2.7? They both can live along on the same system. You can run python3 by calling python3. You can set your preferred version (what is executed by calling python to python3), but beware if there are some system scripts needing python2 but not explicitly specifying it you might break things.

For a script that should be executed by python3 you can write:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
...
```

If you need a newer python3 install or guarantee its own name space (without modifying the system configuration) you need to work with virtual environments and custom distros like [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/).

Comment: I am doing an online course where python 3 is used, so thought it would be better to upgrade to avoid unnecessary troubles in the future. Anyhow thanks, I would try to set up the virtual environment

Comment: @KyathariHrushikesh Just run `sudo apt install python3 python3-all`. If you *really* need the latest Python then I suggest you look into using [PyENV](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to do a Python install of the version you *want* in your userspace and set that as your local user shell to execute things with. You can then execute Python scripts from that by calling `python3 script.py` and then provided PyEnv has set a local shim for you to use for Python calls, it'll use the version of Python you specify. Without breaking system Python libs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ThomasWard that was very helpful